# Providing a default value for InArgument<T>

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4

Old `System.ComponentModel` provides a `DefaultValueAttribute` that, when applied to a property, marks it as having a default value in tools such as the Windows Forms Designer.

Is there an equivalent attribute in the WPF/Workflow Foundation world? The following didn't work as expected:

```
[DefaultValue('|')] // From System.ComponentModel
public InArgument<char> ColumnSeparator { get; set; }
```

The WPF Designer ignores this attribute declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is to implement [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx), and within the `Create` method set all your defaults.

You can have your Activity implement this in order to keep the fuss and muss down.

```
public sealed class MyActivity : NativeActvity, IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Create(DependencyObject target) { /*...*/ }
    // snip
```

Doing your configuration/initialization in this method will help you avoid all the odd corner cases you may strike when trying to initialize your Activities.  You can also perform a cast on that `target` and get everything you need from the state of the workflow within the design surface (e.g., automatically binding to properties).

IActivityTemplateFactory is pretty powerful.  It isn't limited to just adding a single Activity.  Hell, you could drop in a fully built out subassembly, so to speak, of a workflow.  Its good stuff.